# Accessing Email Synchronization Setting

Tags: android, iphone, ios, email, synchronization

I have to access email synchronization settings and disable it through my native app for a specific time period. Is this possible?

I want to do this for Android & iOS both.

Thanks

Comment: There are dozens, perhaps hundreds, of email clients for Android. Please contact each one of their developers individually to determine whether or not they support any sort of API.

Comment: In every android device setting there's a option 'Accounts & Sync' and in the section there's a list of managed accounts like Google, Facebook, Twitter etc, & in those individual option like Google there's a option to sync 'GMAIL' i want to access that & un-check that option so that It doesn't sync when other apps does.

Answer (score 0):

You assume that all email clients use "Accounts & Sync". I will be stunned if that is the case.

That being said, you are welcome to experiment with `setIsSyncable()` or `setSyncAutomatically()` on `ContentResolver`. These should require `WRITE_SYNC_SETTINGS`, which is a "dangerous"-level permission.